# Panasonic: misc files stored on memory card

Tags: memory-card, panasonic, file

This may be a Panasonic-specific question. My camera is a DMC-FT2.

On the memory card, apart from the JPG files a lot of other file types can be found. Do you know what they contain and what they are for?

```
\DCIM
  \100_PANA
    +P1000001.JPG, etc.     photos
\MISC                       empty folder
\PRIVATE
  \AVCHD
    \AVCHDTN
      +THUMB.DTD            about 2MB, contains thumbnails of movies?
      +THUMB.TID            about 2KB, maybe some kind of index
    \BDMV
      \CLIPINF
        +00000.CPI, etc.    ?? 1 per movie
      \PLAYLIST
        +00000.MPL, etc.    ?? only a few, seems to group up several movies together
      \STREAM
        +00000.MTS, etc.    the movies themselves
      +INDEX.BDM            small file, probably index
      +MOVIEOBJ.BDM         small file, probably index
    \IISVPL
      +00000.VPL, etc.      ?? only a few, one per playlist
  \MODELINF
    +MODELINF.DAT           just contains one line with the name of the camera
```

Do you know of any reference information that would explain all of this?

Answer (score 3):

The AVCHD directory is for video files. I asked a similar question on another site (can't find it at the moment though). But it looks like you've gotten the gist of what they do. [Wikipedia's page on AVCHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVCHD#Overview) lists this structure as well:

[image]

Not sure where there is an official reference though.